# Adding Search view in recycler view when adapter is in the same activity

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, searchview

I need a searchview in my recycler view.  The recycler view should be invisible and once we search, the results should be visible.But I m unable to do it please help me. I m working in Android 7 and using firebase as a server. I LL paste the activity. (ChatsFragment and Contacts). I already searched for this question. But they are using adapter as a separate class. But in my code adapter is in the same activity. I m new to Android. So I don't know. I m building a chat application using codes available in the internet. Thanks in advance.

````
 public class ChatsFragment extends Fragment
{
    private View PrivateChatsView;
    private RecyclerView chatsList;

    private DatabaseReference ChatsRef, UsersRef;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private String currentUserID="";


    public ChatsFragment() {

    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        PrivateChatsView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chats, container, false);


        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        currentUserID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        ChatsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Contacts").child(currentUserID);
        UsersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");


        chatsList = (RecyclerView) PrivateChatsView.findViewById(R.id.chats_list);
        chatsList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));


        return PrivateChatsView;
    }


    @Override
    public void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();


        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Contacts> options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Contacts>()
                .setQuery(ChatsRef, Contacts.class)
                .build();


        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Contacts, ChatsViewHolder> adapter =
                new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Contacts, ChatsViewHolder>(options) {
                    @Override
                    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ChatsViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Contacts model)
                    {
                        final String usersIDs = getRef(position).getKey();
                        final String[] retImage = {"default_image"};

                        UsersRef.child(usersIDs).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
                            {
                                if (dataSnapshot.exists())
                                {
                                    if (dataSnapshot.hasChild("image"))
                                    {
                                        retImage[0] = dataSnapshot.child("image").getValue().toString();
                                        Picasso.get().load(retImage[0]).into(holder.profileImage);
                                    }

                                    final String retName = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                                    final String retStatus = dataSnapshot.child("status").getValue().toString();

                                    holder.userName.setText(retName);


                                    if (dataSnapshot.child("userState").hasChild("state"))
                                    {
                                        String state = dataSnapshot.child("userState").child("state").getValue().toString();
                                        String date = dataSnapshot.child("userState").child("date").getValue().toString();
                                        String time = dataSnapshot.child("userState").child("time").getValue().toString();

                                        if (state.equals("online"))
                                        {
                                            holder.userStatus.setText("online");
                                        }
                                        else if (state.equals("offline"))
                                        {
                                            holder.userStatus.setText("Last Seen: " + date + " " + time);
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        holder.userStatus.setText("offline");
                                    }

                                    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(View view)
                                        {
                                            Intent chatIntent = new Intent(getContext(), ChatActivity.class);
                                            chatIntent.putExtra("visit_user_id", usersIDs);
                                            chatIntent.putExtra("visit_user_name", retName);
                                            chatIntent.putExtra("visit_image", retImage[0]);
                                            startActivity(chatIntent);
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                            }
                        });
                    }

                    @NonNull
                    @Override
                    public ChatsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i)
                    {
                        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.users_display_layout, viewGroup, false);
                        return new ChatsViewHolder(view);
                    }
                };

        chatsList.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.startListening();
    }




    public static class  ChatsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        CircleImageView profileImage;
        TextView userStatus, userName;


        public ChatsViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView)
        {
            super(itemView);

            profileImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.users_profile_image);
            userStatus = itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_status);
            userName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_profile_name);
        }
    }
}```








This is Contacts.java 


```public class Contacts {
    public String name, status, image;

    public Contacts()
    {

    }

    public Contacts(String name, String status, String image) {
        this.name = name;
        this.status = status;
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
}```





![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhKSc.jpg)![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqgUi.jpg)![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUaNK.jpg)![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1nnQ.jpg)![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Qfed.jpg)
````

Answer (score 0):

you can use editText with on text change listener
`

```
    etSearchWord.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {

        }

        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
         //here you can hide the recycleView
        }

        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {

            if (s.toString().isNotEmpty()) {
                rvAutoCompResult.visible()
                autoCompleteItems(s.toString())
            } else
                rvAutoCompResult.gone()

        }
    })
```

`
And in you adapter, you can use Filterable to filter your data

Comment: can you please explain in detail. I don't know what is rvAutoCompResult ???

Comment: Please some one help with this... I m unable.. I m.woking on it for 3 days

Comment: rvAutoCompResult.visible() this is for my recycle view that I set my data in